# Proper handling of member function pointers

Tags: c++, c++11

I wrote a generic class for handling and executing a function pointer. This is a simplified equivalent of `std::function` and `std::bind`. To handle member functions I use cast to internal `EventHandler::Class` type. Question: is it ok to cast it that way? Will it work in all cases when invoking handled function?

```
template <typename ReturnType, typename... Arguments>
class EventHandler
{
    class Class {};
    ReturnType (Class::*memberFunction)(Arguments...) = nullptr;
    union {
        Class *owner;
        ReturnType(*function)(Arguments...) = nullptr;
    };

    public:

        EventHandler() = default;
        EventHandler(EventHandler &&) = default;
        EventHandler(const EventHandler &) = default;
        EventHandler &operator=(EventHandler &&) = default;
        EventHandler &operator=(const EventHandler &) = default;

        EventHandler(ReturnType (*function)(Arguments...)) :
            function(function)
        {
        }

        template <typename Owner>
        EventHandler(Owner *owner, ReturnType (Owner::*memberFunction)(Arguments...)) :
            memberFunction((ReturnType (Class::*)(Arguments...)) memberFunction),
            owner((Class *) owner)
        {
        }

        template <typename Owner>
        EventHandler(const Owner *owner, ReturnType (Owner::*memberFunction)(Arguments...) const) :
            memberFunction((ReturnType (Class::*)(Arguments...)) memberFunction),
            owner((Class *) owner)
        {
        }

        ReturnType operator()(Arguments... arguments)
        {
            return memberFunction ?
                (owner ? (owner->*memberFunction)(arguments...) : ReturnType()) :
                (function ? function(arguments...) : ReturnType());
        }
};
```

The implementation provides handle for a global function, a member function and a `const` member function. Obviously there is `volatile` and `const volatile` that is not show here for clarity.

**EDIT**

All the code below is just a representation of all of kinds of supported functions.

```
class Object
{
    public:

        double y = 1000;
        Object() = default;
        Object(double y) : y(y) {}

        static void s1(void) { std::cout << "s1()" << std::endl; }
        static void s2(int a) { std::cout << "s2(a:" << 10 + a << ")" << std::endl; }
        static void s3(int a, float b) { std::cout << "s3(a:" << 10 + a << ", b:" << 10 + b << ")" << std::endl; }
        static int s4(void) { std::cout << "s4(): "; return 10 + 4; }
        static Object s5(int a) { std::cout << "s5(a:" << 10 + a << "): "; return Object(10 + 5.1); }
        static float s6(int a, Object b) { std::cout << "s6(a:" << 10 + a << ", b:" << 10 + b.y << "); "; return 10 + 6.2f; }

        void m1(void) { std::cout << "m1()" << std::endl; }
        void m2(int a) { std::cout << "m2(a:" << y + a << ")" << std::endl; }
        void m3(int a, float b) { std::cout << "m3(a:" << y + a << ", b:" << y + b << ")" << std::endl; }
        int m4(void) { std::cout << "m4(): "; return ((int) y) + 4; }
        Object m5(int a) { std::cout << "m5(a:" << y + a << "): "; return Object(y + 5.1); }
        float m6(int a, Object b) { std::cout << "m6(a:" << y + a << ", b:" << y + b.y << "); "; return ((int) y) + 6.2f; }

        void c1(void) const { std::cout << "c1()" << std::endl; }
        void c2(int a) const { std::cout << "c2(a:" << y + a << ")" << std::endl; }
        void c3(int a, float b) const { std::cout << "c3(a:" << y + a << ", b:" << y + b << ")" << std::endl; }
        int c4(void) const { std::cout << "c4(): "; return ((int) y) + 4; }
        Object c5(int a) const { std::cout << "c5(a:" << y + a << "): "; return Object(y + 5.1); }
        float c6(int a, Object b) const { std::cout << "c6(a:" << y + a << ", b:" << y + b.y << "); "; return ((int) y) + 6.2f; }
};

void f1(void) { std::cout << "f1()" << std::endl; }
void f2(int a) { std::cout << "f2(a:" << a << ")" << std::endl; }
void f3(int a, float b) { std::cout << "f3(a:" << a << ", b:" << b << ")" << std::endl; }
int f4(void) { std::cout << "f4(): "; return 4; }
Object f5(int a) { std::cout << "f5(a:" << a << "): "; return Object(5.1); }
float f6(int a, Object b) { std::cout << "f6(a:" << a << ", b:" << b.y << "); "; return 6.2f; }
```

Here is the usage example for all of the above functions

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "=== Global functions" << std::endl;
    EventHandler ef1(f1); ef1();
    EventHandler ef2(f2); ef2(2);
    EventHandler ef3(f3); ef3(3, 3.1f);
    EventHandler ef4(f4); std::cout << ef4() << std::endl;
    EventHandler ef5(f5); std::cout << ef5(5).y << std::endl;
    EventHandler ef6(f6); std::cout << ef6(6, Object(6.1)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "=== Member static functions" << std::endl;
    EventHandler es1(Object::s1); es1();
    EventHandler es2(Object::s2); es2(2);
    EventHandler es3(Object::s3); es3(3, 3.1f);
    EventHandler es4(Object::s4); std::cout << es4() << std::endl;
    EventHandler es5(Object::s5); std::cout << es5(5).y << std::endl;
    EventHandler es6(Object::s6); std::cout << es6(6, Object(6.1)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "=== Member functions" << std::endl;
    Object object(20);
    EventHandler em1(&object, &Object::m1); em1();
    EventHandler em2(&object, &Object::m2); em2(2);
    EventHandler em3(&object, &Object::m3); em3(3, 3.1f);
    EventHandler em4(&object, &Object::m4); std::cout << em4() << std::endl;
    EventHandler em5(&object, &Object::m5); std::cout << em5(5).y << std::endl;
    EventHandler em6(&object, &Object::m6); std::cout << em6(6, Object(6.1)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "=== Member const functions" << std::endl;
    const Object constObject(30);
    EventHandler ec1(&constObject, &Object::c1); ec1();
    EventHandler ec2(&constObject, &Object::c2); ec2(2);
    EventHandler ec3(&constObject, &Object::c3); ec3(3, 3.1f);
    EventHandler ec4(&constObject, &Object::c4); std::cout << ec4() << std::endl;
    EventHandler ec5(&constObject, &Object::c5); std::cout << ec5(5).y << std::endl;
    EventHandler ec6(&constObject, &Object::c6); std::cout << ec6(6, Object(6.1)) << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Finally - to the point - here an example that shows how much easier in use is the EventHandler I prepared when compared to `std::function` interface. And actually the reason of such approach.

```
    EventHandler<float, int, Object> example;

    example = f6;
    example(7, Object(7.1));

    example = EventHandler(&object, &Object::m6);;
    example(8, Object(8.1));
```

Comment: why do you cast ? A c-style cast is almost always wrong. When you cannot replace it with `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` you should reconsider what you are doing

Comment: `Class` has no member methods, why do you think it would be good to cast things to member function pointer of `Class` ?

Comment: Its unclear what the intended use is. You should post an example not just the template

Comment: why are you trying to reimplement `std::function`?

Comment: no, the casts are not "ok". I actually doubt that this will work for any case without invoking undefined behavior. Tbh it is unclear why you are doing any of this

Comment: If you cast a function pointer you almost always lose. The caller is expecting an exact interface, and even when the caller can survive, the [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) can shoot the program in the head.

Comment: IMHO, poor coding standards to allow `Class` as a class name.  Class names should not be even close to C++ keywords.

Comment: why are you not using `ReturnType (Owner::*)(Arguments...)` ? Whats the purpose of `Class` ?

Comment: Thank you for all of the comments. I added more explanation. Should be more clear now.

Comment: There are several issues with your code and it will not work as already pointed out by the other commenters. If you give more details on what you actually want to achieve, maybe there is a simpler approach? What makes you say, that using `EventHandler` is so much simpler than `std::function`?

Comment: I don't see how what you are doing is much easier (or any easier) than whatever the standard offers. Perhaps you want to show us a side by side comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s undefined behavior to call a function through a function pointer(-to-member) of a different **type**.  (Some practical reasons for this rule are that the object’s address might need to be adjusted to call a member function of a base class or that a vtable might be involved.)  You can use **type erasure** to allow calling member functions on objects of different types (retaining your interface like that of `std::bind`), or you can (restrict to member functions and) add the class type as a template **parameter**.

Of course, the usual answer is to just use `std::function` with a **lambda** that captures the object in question and calls whatever member function.  You can also take the C approach and define various functions with a **`void*`** parameter that cast that parameter to a known class type and call the desired member function.

Comment: That kind of answer I was waiting for. Thank you.